# Linked List clear() function and destructor

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, implementation, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm working on Linked List Implementation. I need to delete some dynamic memory using the `clear()` function, but it gives me an error:

> malloc: *** error for object 0x100105400: pointer being freed was not allocated

When I comment out the `clear()` function, my destructor gives me the same error, but where the `delete` is.

From the error message, I think I delete an unallocated memory, but I can't find it. What do you think I did wrong here? Do you have any suggestion?

```
template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::clear(){
    node* temp = head;
    while (temp != NULL){
        head = head->next;
        delete temp;
        temp = head;
    }
    head = NULL;
    tail = NULL;
    size = 0;
}

template <typename T>
LinkedList<T>::~LinkedList(){
    node* current = head;
    while (head != NULL){
        current = head->next;
        delete head;
        head = current;
    }
    size = 0;
 }
```

And below is my Flight.cpp file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <ostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include "Flight.h"

Flight::Flight(){

}

Flight::~Flight(){
    LinkedList<LinkedList<ArrivalCity>>::node* temp =    flightWeb.getNodeAtIndex(0);
    while(temp != NULL){
        temp->data.clear();
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    flightWeb.clear();
}

void Flight::modifyCitiesLinkedList(ArrivalCity& city_1, ArrivalCity& city_2){

int position = 0;

//check if city1 existed. if yes, just add the object of arrival city to corresponding list. if no, create a new node to flightWeb and add object to corresponding list
if(startingCityRepeated(city_1.getName(), position) == true){
    flightWeb.getNodeAtIndex(position)->data.addNode(city_1);
} else {
    LinkedList<ArrivalCity>* newNode = new LinkedList<ArrivalCity>;
    newNode->addNode(city_1, city_1.getName());
    flightWeb.addNode(*newNode, city_1.getName());
}

position = 0;
//check if city2 existed. if yes, just add the object of arrival city to corresponding list. if no, create a new node to flightWeb and add object to corresponding list
if(startingCityRepeated(city_2.getName(), position) == true){
    flightWeb.getNodeAtIndex(position)->data.addNode(city_2);
} else {
    LinkedList<ArrivalCity>* newNode = new LinkedList<ArrivalCity>;
    newNode->addNode(city_2, city_2.getName());
    flightWeb.addNode(*newNode, city_2.getName());
}
}

//return false: no matching cities existed
//return true: found the matching city
bool Flight::startingCityRepeated(std::string city, int& position){

//no elements in the list, return false, no need to check
if(flightWeb.getSize() == 0){
    return false;
}

LinkedList<LinkedList<ArrivalCity>>::node* temp = flightWeb.getNodeAtIndex(0);

while(temp != NULL){
    //city node existed, return true;
    if(temp->name == city){
        return true;
    }
    temp = temp->next;
    position++;
}
//no matching name found, return false
return false;
}


int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {

Flight flight;
flight.readFlightRoute(argc, argv);
//flight.printStartingCities();
//flight.printArrivalCities();
//flight.totalAvailableFlight();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you allocate nodes?

Comment: Please, add an [MCVE]. Error is likely to be in allocation code.

Comment: Likewise, is the issue in clear() only? I feel like the destructor since it is doing the same thing, is a double free.

Comment: You are probably storing a local variable in the list, but without more code, it's hard to say.

Comment: In your destructor you delete the head which could point to null or garbage depending on the way you initialize each node

Comment: Why do you have 2 methods that suppose to do the same thing? Why not just call `clear` from dtor?

Comment: This is likely caused by a violation of the Rule of Three.

Comment: You have memory leaks all over the place:  `LinkedList<ArrivalCity>* newNode = new LinkedList<ArrivalCity>; newNode->addNode(city_2, city_2.getName()); flightWeb.addNode(*newNode, city_2.getName());`  -- This is a memory leak, and you have the same coding in different places.  You allocated a pointer, and you have no way to call `delete` on it because you've left the `{ }` block where the pointer was allocated in.

Comment: In addition, your `Flight` object should not be allocating anything.  The only entity that should be allocating memory is your LinkedList to create its nodes and internal structure.  Instead, you're writing your `Flight` object as if it's part of the linked list implementation.  The linked list is the only thing that should know about nodes, links, etc.

Comment: I clear the linked list when I delete the Flight object in main which I will include later. There are other functions in Flight class, so I forgot to include the Flight destructor. Sorry for the confusion. I will edit the post and let you see

Comment: @NinaDang A destructor will not help with the code I pointed out.  You allocated memory, and the pointer returned is lost.  You can never call `delete` on that value.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie : Thank you for taking time to help me. I have been looking at the code for hour, but still can't find the bug. So back to problem, I actually need to use them for other functions till the end. I delete them later in destructor of Flight object (~Flight). When Flight object gets out of scope(will be deleted), it will invoke clear() to delete whatever in LinkedList<LinkedList<ArrivalCity>>. Is it right or I have to do it in main?

Comment: *I delete them later in destructor of Flight object* -- No, you can't delete them, because *the pointer values no longer exist*.  You leaked them.   The call to `new` returns a value.  You are to save that value later so that you can call `delete` on that value.  You never saved the pointer value anywhere.  Yes, you **dereferenced** the pointer, but what about the pointer value itself?  It's gone as soon as the `}` is reached, thus the leak.

Comment: If you use a debugger you will see that `newNode` is set to a certain value from the return of `new`.  Write that value down.  Now as soon as you leave that `else` block, where did that value go?  Can you get it back so that you can later call `delete` on it?  No.  That is the essence of what I'm trying to explain.

Comment: I see what you mean. So if after I add newNode, can I delete the pointer since the value was already stored in the LinkedList? And I see where the problem is. I used getNodeAtIndex and accessed data to add a newNode which is wrong because they are private. So I'm making a new function called setNodeAtIndex to modify nodes. I will fix both and let's see

Answer (score 2):

The fact that you commented out the `clear()` function does not tell us anything; either what you really commented out was **all invokations of** `clear()`, or you did in fact comment-out `clear()`, which would mean that `clear()` was not being invoked from your code, (otherwise your program would not compile anymore,) and commenting out a function which is not invoked has no effect.

The following:

```
while (current != NULL)
while (head != NULL){
```

is two (badly indented) nested loops which cannot possibly be what you intended to do.

It is hard to tell without a complete, self-contained, runnable example, but what will probably happen is that the first execution of the inner loop will clear your list, and then the outer loop will iterate once more, with both `current` and `head` pointing at the last node, which has already been deallocated, and thus the error.

Instead of all this convoluted stuff, just invoke `clear()` from within your destructor.

Comment: And first thing to do is to set `head` to `NULL` in the constructor (we did not see the constructor code)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre ah, right, that could also have the same effect, and it is quite plausible.  I think when you try to deallocate a block of memory that has already been allocated and deallocated, most modern C++ runtimes give a message saying that the block has already been deallocated, instead of a message saying that the block has not been allocated.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. There's no while(current !=null) here. I tried other methods and I forgot to delete it. I just edited my code

Comment: and as Mike said, really focus on the `clear` method and invoke it from your destructor instead of copying/pasting almost identical code. Much easier to maintain.